# Return Optional.empty() globally from Spring Webclient on not found response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

When web client receives status 404, I would like to return Optional.empty(). I managed it per each client call

```java
public Optional<User> getUser(Username username) {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(buildUrl(username))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(User.class)
            .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, e -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(e.getStatusCode()) ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(e))
            .blockOptional();
}
```

Above code works well. However, I have many different calls and would like to extract this behavior in the web client builder globally. This is my current code:

```java
        Function<ClientResponse, Mono<ClientResponse>> webclientResponseProcessor = clientResponse -> {
            HttpStatusCode responseStatus = clientResponse.statusCode();
            if (responseStatus.value() == 404) {
                return Mono.empty(); //this doesn't work
            }
            if (responseStatus.is4xxClientError() || responseStatus.is5xxServerError()) {
                return clientResponse.createError();
            }
            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        };
        return WebClient.builder()
                        .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(webclientResponseProcessor))
                        .build();
```

However, returning `Mono.empty()` results in

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client completed
> without emitting a response.
> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient.lambda$static$0(DefaultWebClient.java:77)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)

What am I missing?

Comment: use the `onStatus` operator https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve

Comment: @Toerktumlare I understand usage of onStatus per each call but my first example already works. How do I use onStatus in WebClient builder with ExchangeFilterFunction?